# How to detect when daydream starts/ends

Tags: android, screensaver

In jellybeam mr2 daydream replaced display sleep. An application was able to know when the sleep starts or ends by registering broadcast receiver for action ACTION_SCREEN_ON, ACTION_SCREEN_OFF. Is there any way to do the same against daydream?

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to add a new daydream service, but just want to be informed of (any) daydream-related events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

register for

```
Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED and Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have searched harder :)