# How to detect if Daydream is on?

Tags: android, screensaver

Is it possible to detect if Daydream is on or off? If so, how?

Edit: To clarify, I looking to read the system setting for DayDream (much like you can for airplane mode and other settings). You can infer that from Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED and Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @chrisoff If my answer below was what you were looking for, feel free to mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231082/how-to-detect-when-daydream-starts-ends) answer says you can use:

```
Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED and Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED
```

for broadcast events.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED) is documentation

Comment: I saw that answer. I'm looking to read the system setting, not listen for the intent receiver. I edited my response to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a little utility class to get some Daydream settings:

- Get if Daydream is enabled in the settings
- Get which Daydream is selected in settings
- (get if Daydream is possible on this device)

You can find it here: https://github.com/PieterAelse/blendle/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/piotapps/blendle/utils/DayDreamUtils.java

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to listen to the broadcasts, may be you can check the dumpsys of the dream service:

From the [code](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/dreams/DreamController.java#106), if the current dream is null (which is the case if the daydream is stopped), it will dump

```
"Dreamland:
  mCurrentDream: null"
```

You can check against this value and detect if daydream is on.